# How to use augtool without a lense?

Tags: linux, bash, puppet, augeas

`augtool` [Augeas](http://augeas.net) seams to be a popular program for Puppet to modify config files, but how do I modify a config file where `augtool` doesn't have a lense for? E.g.:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Compiz
Exec=compiz
NoDisplay=false
# name of loadable control center module
X-GNOME-WMSettingsModule=metacity
```

In this particular example would I like to change `NoDisplay` to `true`.

**Question**

Is it possible to modify config files without a lense? Can `augtool` try to guess the tree structure of a config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Augeas cannot guess which lens to use. For example, in the case of a Desktop file (your example), many lenses could be used (`MySQL.lns`, `PHP.lns`, etc.) but each of them would introduce restrictions that would not be compatible with the Desktop format.

In your case, you want to use the `Desktop.lns` lens:

```
$ augtool --autosave --noautoload --transform "Desktop.lns incl /path/to/your/example.desktop" set "/files/path/to/your/example.desktop/Desktop Entry/NoDisplay" true
```

Answer (score 1):

No, augeas is not able to operate without a suitable lense. (Adding those is supposedly pretty difficult, too).

Your example looks like a pretty common `ini` type config file, though. Have you tried the [IniFile](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/inifile-aug.html) lens?

Comment: Can it be done from commandline or only from interactive mode? Have tried `augtool ls -f /augeas/load/IniFile/lens Puppet.lns /files/tmp/t`